# Speech to text using TensorFlow

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, tensorflow

I'm new to TensorFlow and I am looking for help on a speech to text recognition project. Is there an example that showcases how to use TensorFlow for speech to text? I hear that it was used within Google to improve accuracy by 25%

Answer (score 6):

Although there is no speech to text demo in tensorflow. There are demos involving [sequence-to-sequence modelling](http://tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq/index.md) which can be easily used in the context of speech to text.

Comment: Yep, take a look at wavenet: https://github.com/itzikgili/speech-to-text-wavenet